# Criar e excluir campos do formulário

Tags: jquery, ajax

Colegas.

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido dessa vez com PHP do qual cadastro no BD a quantidade de participantes de um determinado evento. Com essas quantidades,crio os campos do formulário. Veja:

```
    <?php
    ....
    while($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlCampos)){
    ?>

    <input type="text" name="NomePessoas[]" class="form-control" maxlenght="100">

    <?php } // Fim do while($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlCampos)) 
?>
```

Até aqui tudo certo, porém preciso fazer com que o usuário exclua ou adicione campos e que ao adicionar/excluir, seja alterado no BD a quantidade cadastrada.

Como eu faria isso no Ajax/Jquery?

Obrigado!

Comment: [Veja este exemplo](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/) de adição de campos com validação dinâmica.

Comment: Você tem de criar uma nova pagina `php`, que será chamada por ajax sempre que o um item for adicionado ou removido, nesta página vc fará o update no banco com base nos parâmetros recebidos, para fazer uma chamada `jQuery` veja esse [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), para duplicar vc pode usar o exemplo dado pelo @BrunoWego.